# How do I send an object through history.push to the page I'm redirected to | REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object (results) from a search bar, I'm trying to send through history.push to the search results page, I'm having trouble being able to access the object through props on the page I'm redirected to. What's the easiest way for me to get redirected to the next page and be able to access the results I'm trying to send there.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Search, List, Form} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {browserHistory,withRouter} from "react-router-dom"
import axios from 'axios';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {query: '', results: [], isLoading: false}
  }

  componentWillMount() {
     this.resetComponent()
   }

   resetComponent = () => this.setState({ isLoading: false, results: [], query: '' })

   search(query) {
     this.setState({ query });
     axios
       .get(`/api/search?query=${query}`)
       .then(response => {
         this.setState({ results: response.data});
       })
       .catch(error => console.log(error));
   }

   handleFormSubmit = () => {
   console.log('search:', this.state.query);
   this.props.action
   this.props.history.push({pathname: `/search/${this.state.query}`, results: `${this.state.results}`})
   this.resetComponent()



 }


  handleInputChange = (query) => {
    this.search(query);
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, query })

    setTimeout(() =>
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
      }) , 300)

  }

  handleResultSelect = (e, { result }) => this.setState({ query: result.title}  )

  render () {

    const resultRenderer = ({ title }) => <List content = {title}/>
    return (

      <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
      <Search
        loading={this.state.isLoading}
        onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
        onSearchChange={(event) => {this.handleInputChange(event.target.value)}}
        showNoResults={false}
        value={this.state.query}
        resultRenderer={resultRenderer}
        results ={this.state.results}
        type={"submit"}
        { ...this.props}  />
      </Form>

    );
  }

}


export default withRouter (SearchBar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `history.push` in 2 ways: with 2 arguments, a path and an optional state `history.push(path, [state])` or a `location` object that contains one or more of the properties `{pathname, search, hash, state}`. Either way you do it, the way that you send custom data to the next location is through the location object's `state`. You're already close, just change this line:

```
this.props.history.push({pathname: `/search/${this.state.query}`, results: `${this.state.results}`})
```

To this

```
this.props.history.push({pathname: `/search/${this.state.query}`, state: {results: `${this.state.results}`}})
```

Then you can access the data in your next component throgh `props.location.state`

Comment: This could be OK to send object to pushState, but remember It has a limit on object sending through method. For example, firefox only allow size limit of 640k characters for this.

Comment: @DatTran Interesting, I did not know that. I've not run into any troubles with it, and `history`'s documentation doesn't specify any kind of limit, maybe it's an abstraction over the regular popState that allows larger objects (most likely). Anyway yes, I wouldn't use this method to send a large data set; it's meant to be used on stuff like sending a redirect url or some search filters, small stuff that doesn't warrant a big state container

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use state container for react. There are several library for that, but Redux is the most common thing working together with react.

The idea is to keep your data of react application centralized in one place, so that you can access it everywhere in the application.

> Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps. (Not to be
>   confused with a WordPress framework – Redux Framework.)
>
> It helps you write applications that behave consistently, run in
>   different environments (client, server, and native), and are easy to
>   test. On top of that, it provides a great developer experience, such
>   as live code editing combined with a time traveling debugger.

You can also visit some tutorial to get started with it: https://medium.com/@notrab/getting-started-with-create-react-app-redux-react-router-redux-thunk-d6a19259f71f

Ref: https://redux.js.org/